# How to check if an element is contained in a list?

Tags: ansible

I have two lists `list1` and `list2`.

`list1` contains a variable amount of names. `list2` contains three constant names.

When I loop over `list1`, how can I write my `when` condition to check if `item` is contained in `list2` ?

This is what I have tried

```
---
- hosts: localhost

  vars:
    list1:
      - user1
      - user2
      - user3
      - userN

    list2:
      - user1
      - user2
      - user3

  tasks:
    - name: check
      debug:
        msg: the "{{item}}" name can be used
      loop: "{{ list1 }}"
      when:  item != list2
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [intersect](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#set-theory-filters) filter might be what you're looking for.

The play below

```
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
     list1:
       - user1
       - user2
       - user3
       - userN
     list2:
       - user1
       - user2
       - user3
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "the {{ item }} name can be used"
      loop: "{{ list1 | intersect(list2) }}"
```

gives (grep msg):

```
"msg": "the user1 name can be used"
"msg": "the user2 name can be used"
"msg": "the user3 name can be used"
```

Answer (score 1):

You were almost there.

- You have an error in your `msg` param: double quotes must be all around the string not just arround the jinja2 template var
- Your test should use the [`in`](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/#other-operators) jinja2 operator

Here is an example playbook

*Note*: It's unclear in your question whether you want to check names **part of** or **not part of** the checklist. Depending on your exact requirement, you can easily revert the condition below if needed => `when: item not in authorized_users`.

```
---
- name: Test 'in' operator
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  vars:

    users:
      - user1
      - user2
      - user3
      - userN
      - toto
      - pipo
      - bingo

    authorized_users:
      - user1
      - user2
      - pipo

  tasks:
    - name: Check if user is authorized
      debug:
        msg: "User {{ item }} is authorized"
      loop: "{{ users }}"
      when: item in authorized_users
```

Which results in

```
PLAY [Test 'in' operator] ******************************************************

TASK [Check if user is authorized] *********************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=user1) => {
    "msg": "User user1 is authorized"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=user2) => {
    "msg": "User user2 is authorized"
}
skipping: [localhost] => (item=user3) 
skipping: [localhost] => (item=userN) 
skipping: [localhost] => (item=toto) 
ok: [localhost] => (item=pipo) => {
    "msg": "User pipo is authorized"
}
skipping: [localhost] => (item=bingo) 

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```